# Touch events: handle swipe differently from click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, touch, modernizr

I've got a Backbone app, and I'm using Modernizr.

On touch devices, I can't swipe the page to scroll it down, because touch events are triggering Backbone listeners and a series of complex events, rather than the usual page scroll.

This is my code:

```
 events: function () {
  if (this.modernizr.touch) {
    return {
      'touchstart .hover': 'onTouchStart'
    };
  } else {
    return {
      'mousemove .hover': 'onMouseMove'
    };
  }
}
// onTouchStart and onMouseMove both fire a listener
```

What event should I be using to distinguish swipe from click, so that swipe allows the user to move the page as normal? (I can't easily test on a touch device, just so you know this isn't a lazy question.)

Answer (score -1):

Is your `onTouchStart` function calling `event.preventDefault()`? If so, that’ll stop the event triggering the native swipe-to-scroll behaviour. Removing that call should allow users to scroll normally.

[This HTML5 Rocks article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/touchandmouse/) goes into quite a bit of detail about how touch events propagate/cascade.

---

*Side note:* The pattern you’ve used here makes a few dangerous assumptions IMO:

- By only binding mouse events if `Modernizr.touch` is `false`, users with hybrid devices (touch-capable laptops etc) won’t be able to use the mouse/trackpad; why not just bind both events?
- Some browsers/devices can’t fire `touchstart` *or* `mousemove` (keyboard users, Windows smartphones, etc) so won’t be able to use this functionality; if you bind to `click` events *too* as a fallback, you’d have them covered

I recently [wrote an article](http://www.stucox.com/blog/the-golden-pattern-for-handling-touch-input/) about what I consider the “golden pattern” to cover all eventualities, if you’re interested.

Of course if the functionality those handlers provide is non-critical these things might not be a problem.